# WSO2 API Manager Getting Start

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

This is regarding wso2 APM

1. Is there a getting started guide for those who wanted to start contributing to WSO2 API Manager.
2. Any feature request page where I can see community voted new features on which contribution is required ?
   ​

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get an understanding about the jaggery application structure in the API manager (The UI parts) you can read following tutorials

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/09/customizing-api-store-publisher-part1/

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/08/customizing-api-storepublisher-jaggery-applicationspart2/

this is the structure followed in api manager store, publisher and admin-dashboard jaggery application.

You can read http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/writing-custom-hostobject/ to see how the jaggery application is connected with the java code.

These will give you a basic understanding about the code base of the api manager.

Comment: How we can proxying a simple Spring MVC RESTful web service call? Any guidance doc is much appreciated.. Regards, Neha

Comment: @pashtika . You can expose your backend web service through the api manager. Create an api and add resources you need for that and set the actual backend url as the endpoint. This way the api created in the api manager will act as the proxy. This is the common scenario used in the WSO2 Api manager. You can find example similar to this in the official documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Create+and+Publish+an+API

Comment: Hello Chamila - Your link doesn't say anything about how we can proxy external web service (let's say simple GET web service) of Spring MVC application. Please help.. Thanks, Sayali

Comment: if ur service is 'http://myservice.com' with a resource 'resource' (you access that by GET http://myservice.com/resource), You create an api with a GET resource named  'resource' and add endpoint url as 'http://myservice.com' and publish the api (see previous provided link). Once published,  you can access your backend application through API manager (GET http://<apimanagerhost>:8280/<version>/<context>/resource type of a url. see  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Subscribe+to+an+API). Now API manager acts as a proxy to your backend service.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a getting started guide for those who wanted to start
>   contributing to WSO2 API Manager.

WSO2 API Manager is 100% open source API Management solution. You can find the component source code in github, [component repo](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt) and [product repo](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim)

> Any feature request page where I can see community voted new features
>   on which contribution is required ? ​

You can find those information in the following mailing list

dev@wso2.org is a mailing list to discuss about all WSO2 products.